# What does while ($variable) mean in PHP?

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and am currently constructing a do/while loop from a tutorial. I would understand if the whole condition was `($variable == true)` or `($variable == false)`, however in the tutorial the `while` condition is simply `while($variable)`. Could anyone explain this to me?

Here is the tutorial code.

```
<?php
    $loopCond = false;
    do {
        echo "<p>The loop ran even though the loop condition is false.</p>";
    } while ($loopCond);


    echo "<p>Now the loop is done running.</p>";
?>
```

Comment: When LoopCond is false it will echo Now the loop is done running.

Comment: Also note that a do loop will ALWAYS run at least once, as the while condition is evaluated at the end of the iteration. If this behavior is undesirable, you should use a while loop instead, which evaluates the condition before the iteration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All such conditional statements, including `while` and `if`, are evaluating the given expression against `true`. If the expression results in `true`, the statement executes the action. If it results in `false`, it won't.

`$var == true` is an expression which compares `$var` to `true`. **The result of this expression is either `true` or `false`.** The important point to understand here is *expressions*. Expressions are things which *return values*. Try `var_dump($var == true)` or `var_dump(4 > 6)`. It shows you that the expressions return a boolean value. Here:

```
if ($var == true)
```

first `$var` is compared to `true`, which yields either the value `true` or `false`, which is then evaluated by `if` whether it's `true` or `false`, which then prompts `if` to execute the following statement or not.

In other words: it's redundant.

```
if ($var)
```

This simply causes `if` to evaluate whether `$var` is `true` or `false` and then execute the following statement. The `== true` is essentially already "built in".

The following statements are all essentially equivalent:

```
if ($var)
if ($var == true)
if (($var == true) == true)
if ((($var == true)) == true) == true)
...
```

Comment: You should also mention that if `$var` has set a value like `"random string"` if ($var) will also return true.

Comment: I'm not going to go into explaining the truth tables of PHP in this answer. The rules are the same between `if ($var)` and `if ($var == true)`.

Answer (score 0):

A condition is met, if the value or statement in it is considered as true.

The code `$variable == true` is a statement that looks whether the value of the variable is true and if it is, yields `true` - Or `false` if it is not.

However, as this means, that `$variable` itself can only ultimately be `true` or `false`, you don't even need the statement, as its return value will also be one of those two.

Therefore `$variable` is exactly the same as `$variable == true`.

I hope this made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

A boolean value `true` or `false` should not be used with a redundant `$c == true` as the result is the same as `$c`: `true` or `false`

```
$driving = true;

while ($driving) {
while ($driving == true) { // ugly

while (! $driving) { // while not driving.
while ($driving == false) { // ugly

$drinking = ! $driving;
if ($driving && $drinking) {
```

Hence also use adjectives for boolean variables.

Answer (score 0):

The semantic of while/do-while is

```
   while(<boolean expression>) {
       // do your stuff
   }
```

A *boolean expression* is anything that *evaluates* to `true` or `false`. So, if `$loopCount` is `true`, then `$loopCount == true` is checked on every loop and evalutes to `true`. But you could also write $`LoopCount` as condition, since it also evaluates to true.

This is very handy for using other data types, e.g. integers.

```
$count = 0;
while ($count < 10) { 
    $count = $count +1;
}
```

Here `$count < 10` is a *boolean expression* that evaluates to `true` as long as `$count` is not higher then 9.

A while loop runs as long as the *condition* is met, in other words, as long as the *boolean expression* you provide evaluates to `true`.

You can also just use a variable, e.g. `$loopCount` when that variable evaluates to a *boolean* or a constant (even the constant value `true`).

Answer (score 0):

Like Padarom said: Therefore $variable is exactly the same as $variable == true.

**In your case**: The while-do loop determines if redo the loop-body after the first run. Means the loop-body is executed exactly one time regardless what value $variable has. After the first run, the `while($variable)` checks if the expression is `true`. If so, the loop-body is executed second time and so forth.

Check PHP reference for do-while loops here. [PHP.net do-while reference](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php)

Answer (score -1):

`while ($loopCond)` and `while ($loopCond == true)` is the same thing. It checks the "trueness" of whatever you put in the brackets.

Answer (score -3):

If I ask a question "does sun set in the west ? " what would be your answer, definitely YES OR TRUE. Same as compiler always look for statement value. Take a look

```
        $condition = true;
        if($condition == true )
         // above will return TRUE; in short $condition == true will replaced by true at runtime.  But if we place true directly which is $condition value or can say we place $condition instead true  thus statement become shorten and look like...
        if($condition) {
         }
```